# Duplicate error message for reCaptcha in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, recaptcha

For some odd reason, my reCaptcha errors for failed verification keeps duplicating, like this:

[image]

Here's my controller code:

```
def create
        #render plain: params[:student].inspect
        @student = Student.new(student_params)
        @recaptcha_succeeded = verify_recaptcha(model: @student)
        if verify_recaptcha(model: @student) && @student.save
            redirect_to @student
        else
            render 'new'
        end
```

Here's the view html code:

```
<%if @recaptcha_succeeded==false%>
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h5><%=@student.errors.size%> error prohibited this student from being saved:</h5>
                    <%@student.errors.full_messages.each do |message|%>
                      <li><%=message%></li>
                    <%end%>
                  </div>
              <%end%>
```

Any tips on why it is so?

Comment: can you show us your `verify_recaptcha` method?.

Comment: @sureshprasanna70 it uses the recaptcha gem from https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha , for the specific verify_recaptcha method, it is located here, https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha/blob/master/lib/recaptcha/adapters/controller_methods.rb

Comment: Feel free to upvote the answer.

Comment: @sureshprasanna70 "[What happens if you answered a question, questioner says thanks, but didn't accept your answer as correct?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109773/what-happens-if-you-answered-a-question-questioner-says-thanks-but-didnt-acce)"

Comment: Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling verify_recaptcha method twice and hence those two errors.You can avoid calling twice by using the result of `verify_recaptcha` stored in `@recaptcha_succeeded` variable.

```rb
def create
        #render plain: params[:student].inspect
        @student = Student.new(student_params)
        @recaptcha_succeeded = verify_recaptcha(model: @student)
        if @recaptch_succeeded && @student.save
            redirect_to @student
        else
            render 'new'
        end
end
```